# Transform input stream to key-values pairs stream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark and Scala so my question probably is rather easy but I still struggle to find an answer. I need to join two Spark streams but I have problems with converting those streams to appropriate format. Please see my code below:

```
val lines7 = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9997)
val pairs7 = lines7.map(line => (line.split(" ")[0], line))

val lines8 = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9998)
val pairs8 = lines8.map(line => (line.split(" ")[0], line))

val newStream = pairs7.join(pairs8)
```

This doesn't work because "join" function expects streams in format `DStream[String, String]` and result of map function is `DStream[(String, String)]`  .

And now my question is how to code this map function to get appropriate output (little explanation would be also great)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know Spark, but from what I can see, [DStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream) only takes one type parameter, so a `DStream[String, String]` is not possible.  You probably want something else, but I can't guess what.  Either that, or `DStream[(String,String)]` is what you want, but you just don't know it yet.

Comment: did you import the implicit conversions in `StreamingContext._` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(30))
val lines7 = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9997)
val pairs7 = lines7.map(line => (line.split(" ")(0), line))
val lines8 = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9998)
val pairs8 = lines8.map(line => (line.split(" ")(0), line))
val newStream = pairs7.join(pairs8)

newStream.foreachRDD(rdd => println(rdd.collect.map(_.toString).mkString(",")))

ssc.start
```

The only issue I see is a syntax error on: `line.split(" ")[0]` vs `line.split(" ")(0)` but I guess that would be noticed by the compiler.